# Построение диаграммы в winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего модно построить такую программу. Пишу программу для расчёта двигателя и нужна индикаторная диаграмма но не знаю как её можно осуществить. Можете помочь или если есть нормальная статья где можно посмотреть как строится такие графики и как можно их вывести в .docx и в .pdf 
Слышал про OxyPlot но не могу найти нормальную статью где нормально объясняют
Заранее спасибо за внимание и за помощь

Comment: Может быть, такую диаграмму проще нарисовать, чем подгонять библиотеки рисования графиков?

Comment: @MBo а с помощью чего можно построить?

Answer (score 2):

Если есть набор рассчитанных точек, то можно провести через них [сплайн](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-cardinal-splines),

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а оси отрисовать [линиями](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-pen-to-draw-lines), добавив подписи